# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable (ItemFrom) was corrupted

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to write this code to do something that relate to my `copyItemFromTree` method, but at the end of my function, I have Run-Time Check Failure #2... error, would you help me to solve this problem?
`pFrom` and `pTo` are `Ctreecntrl` mfc object;

```
TVITEM ItemFrom, ItemTo;
TCHAR szTextFrom[1024];
ItemFrom.pszText = szTextFrom;
ItemFrom.cchTextMax = 1024;
ItemFrom.hItem = hItem;
TCHAR szTextTo[1024];
ItemTo.pszText = szTextTo;
ItemTo.cchTextMax = 1024;
ItemTo.hItem = hItemInTo;

if (pFrom->GetItem(&ItemFrom) && pTo->GetItem(&ItemTo))//I think the problem is here but i don't know how to solve this.
{
    if (ItemFrom.cChildren)
    {
        ItemTo.mask = TVIF_CHILDREN;
        ItemTo.cChildren = ItemFrom.cChildren;
        pTo->SetItem(&ItemTo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely *"Run-Time Check Failure #2"* is because items are not initialized to zero. The mask is not set either. This causes undefined behavior.

Try the following and separate the lines to make it easier to debug:

```
TVITEM ItemFrom = { 0 };
TVITEM ItemTo = { 0 };

TCHAR szTextFrom[1024];
ItemFrom.pszText = szTextFrom;
ItemFrom.cchTextMax = 1024;
ItemFrom.hItem = hItem;
ItemFrom.mask = TVIF_TEXT;

TCHAR szTextTo[1024];
ItemTo.pszText = szTextTo;
ItemTo.cchTextMax = 1024;
ItemTo.hItem = hItemInTo;
ItemTo.mask = TVIF_TEXT;

ASSERT(pFrom->GetItem(&ItemFrom));
ASSERT(pTo->GetItem(&ItemTo));

if (pFrom->GetItem(&ItemFrom) && pTo->GetItem(&ItemTo))
{
    ...
}
```

This line won't copy the children:

```
ItemTo.mask = TVIF_CHILDREN ;
ItemTo.cChildren = ItemFrom.cChildren;
pTo->SetItem(&ItemTo);
```

You have to copy the children one by one from one tree to another. You can try something like the following:

```
if (hItemFrom)
    pTo->InsertItem(pFrom->GetItemText(hItemFrom), hParent);
```

Comment: Thank you, I set the mask and my problem was solved.

Comment: Also make sure to initialize `ItemFrom` and `ItemTo` to zero, I forgot to add line that in an earlier edit.